# Force React to re-render child component created with React.createElement

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router to render at multiple levels (using a framework).

My Index.js has:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={hist}>
<Switch>
  <Route path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
```

Then the AdminLayout class will render a navbar, sidebar, and a main content panel. The content panel is rendered with:

```
<Route
     path={prop.layout + prop.path }
     children={({ match }) => (
         React.createElement(prop.component,{activeEnvironment:this.state.activeEnvironment})
         )}
     key={key}
     />
```

If the this.state.activeEnvironment value changes, I want to force reload the content pane. I'm currently reloading the whole page which works, but isn't clean. Ideally would keep the sidebar and navbar in place, and reload the content pane only.

Does anyone have any suggestions on ways to do this?

Thank you,
Matt

EDIT: The passed state isn't being updated in the child page. However, for application logic/functional reasons, would like to forcefully reload the child page regardless if that is possible. Thank you again..

Comment: where's the problem? `Route` doesn't pass updated value of `activeEnvironment`?

Comment: thats' right.. it doesn't pass the updated state (maybe since it was done with createComponent)? However, even if it does, it may be safest to force reload the child page still (just due to functional/business logic reasons)

Comment: you might try to invalidate `Route`'s `key` on `activeEnvironment` change like `key={key+this.state.activeEnvironment}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marzelin's answer in the below comment solved the issue:

you might try to invalidate Route's key on activeEnvironment change like key={key+this.state.activeEnvironment} – marzelin